# Why is it that this form is being submitted twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, event-handling, form-submit

I am trying to understand why the form in the following snippet is submitted multiple times, after following the steps:

1. Click one of the submit buttons. A confirmation `div` will appear.
2. Click the `Cancel` button in the confirmation.
3. Now click the other submit button.
4. Click the `Yes` button in the confirmation.
5. The console log shows that the form submission handler is fired twice.

Can anyone help me see how/why this is happening, so that I can prevent multiple submissions?

```js
const $form = $("#form-test");
const $confirm = $("#confirm");

$form.on("submit", function (e, $btn) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Submitting!", $btn);
});

$confirm.find("button").on("click", function () {
    $confirm.hide();
});

$form.find("button").on("click", function (e) {
    const $btn = $(this);

    $("#btn-yes").one("click", function () {
        $form.trigger("submit", $btn);
    });

    $("#btn-cancel").one("click", function () {
        console.log("Cancelled!", this);
    });

    $confirm.show();
});
```

```css
#form-container, #confirm {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}

#confirm {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="confirm">
    Are you sure?
    <button id="btn-cancel" type="button">Cancel</button>
    <button id="btn-yes" type="button">Yes</button>
</div>

<div id="form-container">
    <form id="form-test">
        <input type="text" name="test" value="Foo">
        <button type="button">Submit 1</button>
        <button type="button">Submit 2</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You should not find the button instead you should trigger the button using id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running the following:

```
$("#btn-yes").one("click", function () {
    $form.trigger("submit", $btn);
});
```

inside the `$form.find("button").on("click"` handler. If you click into the buttons twice, you'll be adding the handler twice.

Either remove the previous handler before adding the new one, or add the yes/cancel handlers outside (there's no need for them to be added inside the click handler).

```js
const $form = $("#form-test");
const $confirm = $("#confirm");

$form.on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Submitting!");
});

$confirm.find("button").on("click", function() {
  $confirm.hide();
});

$("#btn-yes").one("click", function() {
  $form.trigger("submit");
});
$("#btn-cancel").one("click", function() {
  console.log("Cancelled!", this);
});
$form.find("button").on("click", function() {
  $confirm.show();
});
```

```css
#form-container,
#confirm {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}

#confirm {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="confirm">
  Are you sure?
  <button id="btn-cancel" type="button">Cancel</button>
  <button id="btn-yes" type="button">Yes</button>
</div>

<div id="form-container">
  <form id="form-test">
    <input type="text" name="test" value="Foo">
    <button type="button">Submit 1</button>
    <button type="button">Submit 2</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!